# latexdiff and not showing changes with eurosym

Tags: latexdiff, eurosym

I use `latexdiff` and it works great, apart from currency values for which I use the `eurosym` package. If I have a document `mwe_a.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage[right]{eurosym}

\begin{document}

\blindtext
\EUR{4}
\blindtext Additional text.

\end{document}
```

and a document `mwe_b.tex` where the only change is `\EUR{4}`->`\EUR{5}`, then this change is not visible when using `latexdiff mwe_*.tex > changes.tex`.

The resulting part

```
\DIFdelbegin %DIFDELCMD < \EUR{4}
%DIFDELCMD < %%%
\DIFdelend \DIFaddbegin \EUR{5}
\DIFaddend
```

Has detected the change, but the highlighting fails. How can I make those changes show up?

Comment: You could try option --append-safecmd=EUR. Whether this works or results in error messages depends on how \EUR is implemented. If that does not work try --append-mboxsafecmd=EUR.   Let me know if any of these worked for you

Comment: the first option worked! thanks a lot. If you repost it as answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use option `--append-safecmd=EUR` .

As a precaution, latexdiff excludes commands it does not know about from marking up because the command could cause an error if it is used in the argument of the mark-up command.

With the option you tell latexdiff that it is safe to use this command in the argument of the markup command  (wavy underline by default). Usually this works with symbol-producing commands.